# c# Upload File to SharePoint Document Library

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, .net-4.8

My requirement is the following:

- I have various bits of network hardware, from which we regularly export configurations (this is done using another c#/.NET app I created, this works really well - the tool logs in via SSH to the various devices and downloads the latest configuration to the local hard disk of the server from which the app runs).
- We have various SharePoint online sites (provided via our M365 subscription).
- I want to have these configs uploaded to a particular folder, in a particular document library, in a particular SharePoint Online site, basically so that there is an off-site backup of the config files.

I was following the steps in this blog: https://daoudisamir.com/from-c-to-sharepoint-file-upload-using-csom-with-subfolders-structure/.

It looked like it did what I wanted... but when I try to build the code, it tells me that I'm missing references to assemblies etc. I know that this means that I'm missing "using" directives, but I've tried all sorts of variations to reference the various NUGET packages that are instructed to be installed, but I can't get this to work and couldn't see anywhere on the blog itself to email the owner.

Anyone got any ideas... at the moment, my code is more or less a copy/paste of what's on the blog page, but I've included my code here for convenience:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace UploadToSharePoint_Net48
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string SiteUrl = "https://You.sharepoint.com/sites/Upload";
            string DocumentLibrary = "UploadLibrary";
            string FileName = @"C:\testupload.pdf";
            string CustomerFolder = "1564_dsfgsst";
            string UserName = "samir.daoudi@******.co.uk";
            string Password = "*****";
            UploadFileToSharePoint(SiteUrl, DocumentLibrary, CustomerFolder, FileName, UserName, Password);
        }

        private static void UploadFileToSharePoint(string SiteUrl, string DocLibrary, string ClientSubFolder, string FileName, string Login, string Password)
        {
            try
            {
                #region ConnectToSharePoint

                var securePassword = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in Password)
                { securePassword.AppendChar(c); }
                var onlineCredentials = new SP.SharePointOnlineCredentials(Login, securePassword);
                #endregion

                #region Insert the data
                using (SP.ClientContext CContext = new SP.ClientContext(SiteUrl))
                {
                    CContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
                    SP.Web web = CContext.Web;
                    SP.FileCreationInformation newFile = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
                    byte[] FileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
                    newFile.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(FileContent);
                    newFile.Url = Path.GetFileName(FileName);
                    SP.List DocumentLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocLibrary);
                    //SP.Folder folder = DocumentLibrary.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl(ClientSubFolder);
                    SP.Folder Clientfolder = DocumentLibrary.RootFolder.Folders.Add(ClientSubFolder);
                    Clientfolder.Update();
                    SP.File uploadFile = Clientfolder.Files.Add(newFile);

                    CContext.Load(DocumentLibrary);
                    CContext.Load(uploadFile);
                    CContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("The File has been uploaded" + Environment.NewLine + "FileUrl -->" + SiteUrl + "/" + DocLibrary + "/" + ClientSubFolder + "/" + Path.GetFileName(FileName));
                }

                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(exp.Message + Environment.NewLine + exp.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The errors are with all the references to SP.xxxxx

I can see that there is no definition for anything called "SP", but I'm assuming at this stage that this is in one of the external libraries or whatever is in the NUGETS that are required.

Any help gratefully received.

Thanks

Colin

Comment: It seems the blog post uses `SP` as abbreviation of the actual namespace `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client`.

Comment: Thanks very much @KlausGütter.
That's solved most of the problems - seems that the reference to SharePointOnlineCredentials still doesn't work properly, and there's also some sort of time conversion issue or something like this at newFile.ContentStream... but at least I'm now getting sensible errors and things, so hopefully google is my friend for this now.
Thanks very much.